# How could you add an entity to two different parent entities using linq-to-sql or entity framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Is is possible to add the same entity to two different entities without it duplicating the child entity?  Weird question, I know but here's what I'm trying to do in pseudo code...

```
Transaction tran = new Transaction()

Task task = new Task();
task.Name = "My Task";

User user = new User();
user.Name = "John Smith";
user.Tasks.Add(task);

Document doc = new Document();
doc.Path = @"c:\temp\MyDoc.pdf";
doc.Tasks.Add(task);

tran.Users.Add(user);
tran.Documents.Add(doc);

tran.Create();
```

I'd like the developer to be able to just add the same task object to both the User.Tasks collection and the Document.Tasks collection and so that when I do the insert into the database on the Create() method, it knows that task is related to both the User and the Document via the UserID and DocumentID.

the Task table would have and ID for each:

**Tasks table**

```
ID          int
UserID      int
DocumentID  int
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly simple model would do this:

```
public class Task
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Document Document { get; set; }
  public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Path { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

By default, EF would name the foreign key columns `Document_ID` and `User_ID` (with underscore). If you don't want that you can tell EF that other column names should be used, for example like this (in the `DbContext`):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Document>()
              .HasMany(t => t.Tasks)
              .WithOptional(t => t.Document)
              .Map(m => m.MapKey("DocumentID"));
}
```

Comment: If I'm doing database first and I have the relations mapped with the proper IDs, will I still need to have the OnModelCreating method?

Comment: @RichC No. The edmx contains the model. You're not supposed to override `OnModelCreating`. By default in database-first this override contains `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();`.

Comment: wow, I didn't believe you so I tested it and it _did_ work just like you said. lol  thanks!!